# Jquery image zoom and crop plugin

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

Please let me know that best zoom and crop plugin in jquery , which support all mobile browser  platforms(Android, ios and windows(mandatory) ).

Answer (score 1):

Have a look from [here](https://github.com/fengyuanchen/cropper)

It (https://github.com/fengyuanchen/cropper) provides a range of features. You can use according to your needs. It has cropping, zooming, mobile touch support and documentation is also nice.